# Some clients get 500 error, others 200 response, with 100% consistency

Tags: apache-2.4

What could cause some clients to get 500 errors while others get 200, with complete consistency? I.e. it is not an error that occurs 10% of the time. Instead it occurs with some % of clients ALL the time.

Server is CentOS 6 with Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5, MySQL 5.6, with WHM/cPanel installed.

We recently switched our domain name from `example.com` to `www.example.com` and I wonder if that could have something to do with the problem. The server sends a `301` redirect if `example.com` is requested. And it seems to be working fine. The working and non-working machines both get the `301`, followed by the response from `www.example.com`, which will be either `200` or `500` depending on the client.

Most of our machines are getting `200` response and a full webpage, while a few are getting `500` and a partial page. The partial page loads also have a TTFB that is 30-50% faster than normal.

Clearly, the server is consistently encountering an error whenever it gets requests from certain clients in our network, and probably the problem is widespread. For example, when I tested our site with Google Page Speed insights, the TTFB was too fast *and* Google said they encountered a 500 server error.

With a `200` response, Chrome records 256 requests and 1.8 MB transferred. With the `500` response:  131 requests, 562 KB transferred.

Looking at the server's Apache error_log, I don't even see anything logged from our public IP address today, at all, although there are errors from other IP addresses. But no `500`'s.

Comment: Check your web server logs. Check the logs of whatever is in front of your web server.

Comment: Found it. There was a PHP object that only got created if the user had a session with "recently viewed products" stored in it. So new users would get a "non-object" error when a method was called against the object variable, until they viewed any products.
The strange part is  the server returned part of the webpage AND a 500 error, when usually a PHP fatal error would result in no output except an error page.